# ValueError: Cannot copy sequence to array axis in Python for MatplotLib Animation

Tags: python, valueerror

I am reading in a constantly updated `data.txt` file and am calculating a rolling standard deviation on the incoming data stream.  I am storing that in `std`.  I have a window size of 100 on the rolling standard deviation.

I am receiving an error:

`ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 78 to array axis with dimension 1`

where the size corresponds to the number of items in the `std` array.  (So this, of course, increases every time I hit Run).

I was wondering why I am receiving this ValueError, and am looking for any suggestions to fix it!  The animation works fine when I am just grading `ax1.plot(xar, yar)`.  But once I try to graph `ax1.plot(xar, std)`, the problem arises.

The data in `data.txt` looks as follows:

```
[0.0, 0.0078125, 0.015625][0.0, 0.0078125, 0.015625][0.0, 0.0078125, 0.015625][0.0, 0.0078125, 0.015625][0.0, 0.0078125, 0.015625][0.0, 0.0078125, 0.015625][0.0244140625, 0.0322265625, 0.9609375][0.0244140625, 0.0322265625, 0.9609375][0.0244140625, 0.0322265625, 0.9609375][0.0244140625, 0.0322265625, 0.9609375][0.0244140625, 0.0322265625, 0.9609375][0.0244140625, 0.0322265625, 0.9609375][0.0244140625, 0.0322265625, 0.9609375][0.0244140625, 0.0322265625, 0.9609375][0.0244140625, 0.0322265625, 0.9609375][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.0341796875][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.0341796875][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.0341796875][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.0341796875][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.0341796875][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.0341796875][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.0341796875][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.0341796875][0.0244140625, 0.0341796875, 1.0048828125][0.0244140625, 0.0341796875, 1.0048828125][0.0244140625, 0.0341796875, 1.0048828125][0.0244140625, 0.0341796875, 1.0048828125][0.0244140625, 0.0341796875, 1.0048828125][0.0244140625, 0.0341796875, 1.0048828125][0.0244140625, 0.0341796875, 1.0048828125][0.0244140625, 0.0341796875, 1.0048828125][0.0244140625, 0.0341796875, 1.0048828125][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.033203125, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.033203125, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.033203125, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.033203125, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.033203125, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.033203125, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.033203125, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.033203125, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.0263671875, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.0107421875][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625][0.025390625, 0.0341796875, 1.009765625]
```

My current code is as follows:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data.txt", sep="\[|\]\[|\]",engine = 'python', header = None)
    data = data.iloc[0]
    data = data.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[-1]).astype(float)
    data.pop(0)
    xar = []
    yar = []
    std = []
    for j in range(len(data)):
        xar.append(j)
    for k in range(len(data)):
        yar.append(data.iloc[k])
    yar = pd.DataFrame(yar)
    std.append(pd.rolling_std(yar, 100))
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar,std)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=.01)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is that you `std`becomes a list (of one element) of a data frame. `pd.rolling_std()` is already giving you a data frame, and then you append it to your list. If you just directly assign it, it will work better:

```
std = pd.rolling_std(yar, 100)
```

However, when running `pd.rolling_std()` there is a deprecation warning given. So, the line should rather be:

```
std = yar.rolling(window=100,center=False).std()
```

Also, there are a few more simplifications that can be made as of how you generate `xar` and `yar`. `xar` is just a range and `yar` contains all the elements of `data` allowing you to write:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data.txt", sep="\[|\]\[|\]",engine = 'python', header = None)
    data = data.iloc[0]
    data = data.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[-1]).astype(float)
    data.pop(0)
    xar = range(len(data))
    yar = pd.DataFrame(data)
    std = yar.rolling(window=100,center=False).std()
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar,std)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=.01)
plt.show()
```

where `animate()` has been somewhat simplified.

Comment: Fantastic!  This worked splendidly.  Thanks for your support!  People like you make this community so awesome.

Comment: At the very beginning of the animation, there is a large spike.  How could I go about removing this initial spike in the animation?

Comment: I don't know your exact use case so I don't know. But, when using a rolling average, you have a bunch of nan (not a number) values in the beginning, before you have sufficiently many data points to get your first average (100 in the above code). Thus, there might be a bump when you hit upon 100 elements, where you are going from a nan value to an actual value. Could it be this you see?

Comment: That means there is not much to do about it, since it is a property of the data itself. It may be possible to use fewer values in the initial average, increasing from 1 to 100, but I don't know if that is any better. And it requires more logic.

Comment: Perhaps you may be able to support me with a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358721/differences-in-pd-rolling-std-over-an-entire-dataset-versus-in-real-time

Comment: I see that you have removed the question again. What was the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150351/discussion-between-gary-and-johanl).