# Throwing away 3 out of 4 samples from a data frame

Tags: python

In Python, I have a DataFrame that looks like the following, all the way down to about 5000 samples:

[image]

I was wondering, in `pandas`, how do I remove 3 out of every 4 data points in my `DataFrame`?

Comment: How do you choose which 3 out of every 4 to remove?

Comment: It doesn't matter which, for my use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To obtain a random [sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) of a quarter of your DataFrame, you could use

```
test4.sample(frac=0.25)
```

or, to specify the exact number of rows

```
test4.sample(n=1250))
```

---

If your purpose is to build training, validation, and testing data sets, then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38250710/190597).

Comment: It's not related to machine learning, but rather, related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337886/valueerror-cannot-copy-sequence-to-array-axis-in-python-for-matplotlib-animatio/45342706#45342706

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select every 4th point, then you can do the following. This will select rows 0, 4, 8, ...:

```
test4.iloc[::4, :]['Accel']
```